# Organizing a large number of classes under a Namespace

Tags: namespaces

We are converting windows applications to browser based in .Net using Visual Studio 2010.  While I'm not new to .Net, I am new to creating applications based on 3 tier architecture.  I want to create classes for each table in our database and put them under a Namespace.  The class name will be the same as the table name, so each class in the the Namespace would be referenced something like CompanyName.ProductName.Entity.{table name}.  Now for my questions:

Is this feasable?

Would I create seperate project for each table class?  Note that new table classes will be created as more programs are converted.

Does this create one huge .dll?

How do other developers access the classes I created, and where are they stored so I can reference the classes with the Using directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer that I was looking for is to create one solution with my namespace as the default namespace.  For each file, create a new class, and specify the namespace in each.  Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Always create the class names with individual cs file, so it will be easy to do versioning of files. It does not relate to size of dll if we keep the class in a single file or multiple files.

Create the folder structure like Project > ProductName > Classes in your solution.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that I should create one project in VS called something like My Entities and then add new folders containing each new table class as needed, which creates one .dll.  Is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: There will be a folder specific to an entity that will hold all the classes related to that entity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Would I create seperate project for each table class?
   No, don't create a separate project for each table class. That's too granular.
2. Does this create one huge .dll?
   Each project would create a separate DLL by default (I believe you can do things with IL merge to change that.)  However, each namespace does not have a direct relationship to DLLs.  That is, you can have multiple namespaces in a single DLL.

What we've typically done is create a DAL library.  This would be it's own project, usually named something like `ProductName.Data` Then within that we might have a namespace like `ProductName.Data.Models` or `ProductName.Data.Repositories`.

Namespaces are largely used to help YOU organize the code.  They also help out the compiler.  For example, if you have a database class named `Users`, and it's in `XYZ.Data`, you can still have a view model named `Users` if it's in a separate namespace, e.g. `XYZ.ViewModels`.

Another thing that we've done is to keep the root namespace the same across DLLs for the same product.  So we recently had our database in `XYZ.Data`.  Then we put our application specific logic in a separate DLL and named it `XYZ.AppLogic`  We also had view models in the namespace `XYZ.ViewModels`.

I don't believe there are any hard/fast rules that limit the number of namespaces you have.  By default, Studio will try to create a new namespace for each folder in your project.  That said, I often try to avoid namespace overload, because I don't want to see something like this at the top of my files:

```
using XYZ.Data.Models.Accounts;
using XYZ.Data.Models.Users;
using XYZ.AppLogic.Authentication;
using XYZ.AppLogic.Users;
using XYZ.AppLogic.Settings;
using XYZ.ViewModels.UserPreferences;
```

However, that's more of a personal preference than anything else.

**EDIT Solution View**

- MySolution

  - MyProj.Data

    - Models

      - User.cs
      - Account.cs
      - Settings.cs
  - Repository

    - UserRepository.cs
    - AccountRepository.cs

User.cs is my POCO (Plain Ol' CLR Object) that defines the table.

The Repository folder has things specific to my ORM (I'm using PetaPoco) which let me actually access my user data.

For example, my UserRepository might have a method

```
public User GetById(int id)
{
   var db = new Database(<myConnectionStringName>);
   return db.SingleOrDefault<User>(id);
}
```

That syntax is specific to PetaPoco, but it is how I separate the data object from the actual DB connection.

Comment: I'm referring to all the tables in my database as Entities, but I see your point in your reference to your DAL lib.  I want to group all my tables under a single namespace like MyNamingConvention.Entities.  So far, it sounds like I create one project that will hold all my classes.  As to how to organize them within that project is where I'm getting lost.  If I right click on the project name in solution Explorer, do I add a file then a new class within the new folder, or just continue to add classes with the same namespace declaration?

Comment: I may be using the word project incorrectly - maybe I should be saying solution?

Comment: Yes, add a new file per table. Otherwise the file gets unwieldy quickly.  I typically have a Models folder and then a Repository folder or something like that which actually does the DB work.

Comment: So your Models folder has a sub foldef for each table class?  What is the DB work you are referring to - connection?

Comment: No my models folder has a single cs file per model. I'll update my answer.